# Find a homomorphism phi from U(40) toU(40) kernal{1,9,17,33} and phi (11)=11

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find a homomorphism $phi$ from $U(40)$ to $U(40)$ with kernel ${1,9,17,33}$ and $phi(11)=11$

Iam looking for a solution since I have already tried several times myself.

Comment: Hint: If the homomorphism is not trivial, how large must the kernel be?

Comment: What defines a trivial homomorphism? @TobiasKildetoft, im not quite sure how large the kernel can be, what am i missing?

Comment: By trivial I mean the one that sends everything to the neutral element. For finding the size of the kernel, use an isomorphism theorem (possibly the first, but the numbering is not consistent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to figuring this out is to remember that knowing all homomorphic images of a group is equivalent to knowing all the normal subgroups of a given group (think about the kernel). The theorem that should be familiar to you is

**Theorem:** Let $ \phi : \mathcal{G} \rightarrow \bar{\mathcal{G}} $ be a homomorphism with kernel $K$. Then $ \mathcal{G} / K \approx \bar{\mathcal{G}} $.

What the above says is exactly what I said originally, namely knowing all the normal subgroups of a group gives one *all* the homomorphic images of a group. This is because a normal subgroup can be exclusively defined as the kernel of a homomorphism.

In your case find all normal subgroups of $S_4$ and proceed from there.

Comment: Since we are just looking for $S_4\to\mathbb Z_2$, the images will be of order $1$ or $2$, so the kernels…

Comment: If you are familiar with group homomorphisms then you should be familiar with a theorem which states: If $ \phi : \mathcal{G} \rightarrow \bar{\mathcal{G}} $ with kernel $K$, then $ \mathcal{G} / K \approx \bar{\mathcal{G}}$. Since a normal subgroup is defined as the kernel of a group homomorphism, knowing all the normal subgroups then looking at the quotient groups gives one all homomorphic images of a group

Comment: What I was hinting at is that, since the only divisors of $2$ are $1$ and $2$, we only need to find normal subgroups of order $24$ (trivial) and $12$, not all the normal subgroups.

Comment: @o0BlueBeast0o, im thinking that if $\phi$ is a homomorphism then $ker(\phi)$ must be a normal subgroup of $S_4$, since only 2 such normal subgroups exist we have found our two homomorphisms. Is this correct?

Comment: Essentially yes. What the theorem states is that finding the normal subgroups of $S_4$ and then looking at the corresponding quotient groups, $S_4 / N $, will give you the homomorphic images of the group. Of course there is the homomorphism which maps everything to the identity, this corresponds to $S_4 / S_4 \approx \left< e \right>$.  Now we look for normal subgroups which gives a quotient group that looks like $\mathbb{Z}_2$. We know that the alternating group $A_n$ is always normal in $S_n$ and has order $\frac{1}{2} n!$. $S_n / A_n$ will be the quotient group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Comment: @o0BlueBeast0o, thank you very much. But how can i argue when finding the normal subgroups of $S_4$? Of course I know them (only 2 exist?), but I have to give an argument of how i found them?

Comment: Well my answer really depends on how much groups theory you know. There are two non-trivial normal subgroups yes. If you've developed permutation groups it is rather easy to argue why $A_n$ is normal. This is because $A_n$ consists of all even permutations in $S_n$. Conjugation will not change the parity of a even permutation. This says that $A_n$ is normal in $S_n$. The other non-trivial normal subgroup (which is a four group I believe) shouldn't play a role since its quotient group will have order 6, which is obviously to large for $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Comment: @o0BlueBeast0o according to my calculations I have found that ${(),(1 2)(3 4), (1 3)(2 4), (1 4)(2 3)}$ and $A_4$ aswell as just ${e}$ are the only normal subgroups of $S_4$, is this correct?

Comment: Yes also remembering that $S_4$ is normal in $S_4$